# Building a matrix with columns == days of month when recordset cannot return all days of month

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, bids, fetchxml

I'm trying to put together an attendance report for a school that tracks student attendance codes for that student for every day on the calendar month in a DynamicsCRM system being used as a managed service (that is to say, I build queries using FetchXML and cannot use SQL).  The format for the report requires that a column for every day in the month be listed for the report.  My student table that tracks this attendance however only contains records for days where an attendance value is recorded, and I do not have an object available that can return every day in a month for me.

I am looking for a solution other than hardcoding 31 columns and using conditionals to control the display of the last three day columns.  Ideally, I'd like a conditional in my matrix column grouping that would look at the date value for the previously generated column and determine if the next date record from my resultset is sequentially the next day of that month, and if not, create the next sequential date, move to the next column and perform the check again until it is true.  Is there a way I can do this, or another means to accomplish my goal that does not involve hard-coding day columns into a table or matrix?  Right now, I have nothing; I can barely imagine how I think this should look.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the same issue has been to create a scheduled process each day to create a record and deactivate it.

I have then been able to distinguish actual records (the active ones) from these 'placeholders' (inactive ones) in my querying.

Comment: I might be able to do something like this to solve my problem but it requires me to solicit the work from another member of this project (we're all silo'd and can't work out of our assigned scopes, mine is report writing).  I was hoping more for a solution I could implement in report writer.  But I appreciate the suggestion, I'll consider it if I can't find an answer I can implement myself.